# How to inherit from NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

I have an object called Settings that inherits from `NSMutableDictionary`.  When I try to initialize this object using

```
Settings *settings = [[Settings alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"someFile"]
```

it returns an object of type `NSCFDictionary`.  As a result, it doesn't recognize my additional methods.  For example, when I call the selector "save", it objects:

```
[NSCFDictionary save]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x524bc0
```

Of course, it's OK when I initialize using the garden variety

```
Settings *settings = [[Settings alloc] init]
```

I tried to cast it again to Settings but that didn't work.  This seems really simple - what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: When I read the first sentence I immediately thought that maybe, instead of creating a Settings class, you could use NSUserDefaults? Of course I don't know whether NSUserDefaults would suit your needs, but it's designed to store settings, so there might be no need to build your own. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks.  This does sound like it'll do what I want.  It's not a "default" value per se that I'm storing, but this will probably do just fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NSDictionary is a class cluster. This means that the value returned from its init methods is not strictly an NSDictionary, but a subclass that implements the actual functionality. In almost every case, it is better to give your class an NSDictionary as an instance variable or to simply define a category on NSDictionary.

Comment: Other "classes" like this are (most notably) NSString, NSArray, and NSSet.  I occasionally come across log statements referring to an "NSBigMutableString" that used to boggle me until I learned about class clusters. =)

Comment: I agree with this. Best would probably be to use a has-a relationship, instead of an is-a relationship. (prefer composition over subclassing). You can make your class perform like a dictionary by overriding `-setValue:forKey:` and `-valueForKey:`, etc.

Answer (score 16):

Chuck is correct about NSDictionary (and Dave, by extension, about NSArray/Set/String) and class clusters. Odds are that `-[NSDictionary initWithContentsOfFile:]` calls down to a different initializer than `-init` does, which is why it swaps out your allocated `Settings` instance for another subclass of NSMutableDictionary. (The initialization action when reading from a file may select a particular known subclass of NSDictionary which performs well for loading from a file, etc.)

I'll echo Chuck's guidance that it is *almost always* better to use composition or categories than inheritance for an NSDictionary. It's highly likely that you could accomplish what you're doing with categories in a much simpler way, and expose yourself to fewer potential bugs in the process. Consider yourself warned before deciding to subclass.

That being said, both NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary have been designed to support subclassing, and on rare occasions that's the right thing to do. Think long and hard about it before trying it. If you find it's the right choice for your design, here are some key points to know and do as needed:

1. Override the following primitive methods from [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

   - `-count`
   - `-objectForKey:`
   - `-keyEnumerator`
   - `-initWithObjects:forKeys:count`: (designated initializer)
2. Override the following primitive methods from [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/):

   - `-setObject:forKey:`
   - `-removeObjectForKey:`
3. If you're supporting [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/), be aware of `classForKeyedArchiver` and `replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:` (both instance methods from NSObject) — they can totally change how your class responds, and you often unintentionally inherit some odd behavior from NS(Mutable)Dictionary. (You can verify if they are the culprit by setting a breakpoint on them, or implementing them to call super and breaking on your own code.)

I've implemented a number of these points in an NSMutableDictionary subclass of my own. You can [check it out](https://github.com/davedelong/CHDataStructures/blob/master/source/CHMutableDictionary.m) and use the code however may be helpful to you. One that particularly helped me (and could be the solution for your problem) was overloading the designated initializer, which is currently undocumented (Radar #7046209).

The thing to remember is that even though these bullets cover most common uses, there are always edge cases and less common functionality to account for. For example, `-isEqual:` and `-hash` for testing equality, etc.

Comment: Thanks - you have all sufficiently scared me from sub-classing NSDictionary, at least until I'm more seasoned.  So I am going to either use NSUserDefaults, or else use the composition pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually read the spec for NSDictionary (a rash action, I know) you'll find a section named "Subclassing Notes".  In it you will read:

> If you do need to subclass NSDictionary, you need to take into account
>   that is represented by a Class cluster—there are therefore several
>   primitive methods upon which the methods are conceptually based:
>
> ```
> initWithObjects:forKeys:
>
> count
>
> objectForKey:
>
> keyEnumerator
> ```
>
> In a subclass, you must override all these methods.

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1191351/467588, this is what I did to make a subclass of NSDictionary works. I just declare an NSDictionary as an instance variable of my class and add some more required methods. I don't know what to call them though.

I posted my code sample here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10993594/467588.

Comment: This is similar to what Apple is recommending - a composite object:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4-SW81

Comment: @mahboudz, Why not simply returning from the method if it's not valid, and if it is, change `self`, instead of relying on a separate array?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old, and since most of these answers were posted, Apple has introduced [object subscripting](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/), which allows you to make your own classes behave more like `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary`. This is simpler than the alternatives discussed above.

At a minimum, you have to override these methods:

```
//Array-style
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;

//Dictionary-style
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
```

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.thechrisoshow.com/2012/09/21/add-new-objective-c-subscripting-to-your-own-objects/) on how to do just that.