# What is the best way to implement a datasource in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Basically i want a data-structure that i can grow and shrink as and when i get more information on users. I want a flat associative list of usernames with their associated data E.G:

```
` usersDictionary = {
      user_id : {
          id : "0123456789",
          full_name : "Spongebob Jones",
          more_data: {
              likes: "snails"
          }
      },
      next_user_id : {}
  }`
```

Relatively new to Obj-C... I've spiked a datasource, I'm using @interface NSMutableDictionary and building up the user data appending other NSMuteablesDictionaries. All seemed well, however when trying to get the data out i'm getting:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary objectForKey:]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[UsersCollection objectForKey:]!

I read that it's not recommended to implement NSMuteableDictionary directly, as it's a cluster class(?).

I'm looking for some advice on whether or not i'm going about this the correct way, if not please point!

Comment: You should never have an `@interface` that names (as the interface name and not the superclass) an iOS class.

Comment: The above structure can be implemented as either a regular class (or set of classes) or a set of nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you're subclassing NSMutableDictionary rather than trying to redefine it.

You [probably don't want to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191329/how-to-inherit-from-nsdictionary) (scroll past my answer for the nitty-gritty details if you're interested). It is almost always more work than it is worth — simply creating a class that *has* an NSDictionary is usually the better approach.

Comment: Your linked answer regarding the cluster class makes perfect sense as to why my current implementation is broken. I'll implement as you suggested, and make use of nested dictionaries. Cheers.